# How to access namespaced models outside their namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a namespaced controller:

```
dashboard/posts
```

And I also have a model called `Post` in the `frontpage` directory and namespace, i.e:

```
frontpage/Post
```

How do I access the `Post` model from the dashboard namespace?

I essentially want to be able to have dashboard/posts for editing, creating, etc., and frontpage/posts for viewing.

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try calling your Post model this way:

```
@post = ::Frontpage::Post.last
```

Prepending `::` to `Frontpage::Post` tells Rails to look for the namespaced model from the top level.